# Mixing formula for SVJ models

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, jump-diffusion, black-scholes-merton

I am trying to understand the mixing formula (Hull and White formula) for stochastic volatility models with jumps in the asset price. One article which discusses this is [Lewis, The mixing approach to stochastic volatility and jump models, Wilmott, 2002](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Erolf/teaching/ctff03/020328_lewis.pdf).

Is it correct to write the general stock price process in a SVJ model as follows:
$$
S_T = \tilde S_T X_T Y_T
$$
with
$$
\tilde S_T = S_t \exp \left\{ -\frac{1-\rho^2}{2} \int_t^T \sigma^2_u du + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \int_t^T \sigma_u dZ_u  \right\}
$$
$$
X_T = \exp \left\{ -\frac{\rho^2}{2} \int_t^T \sigma^2_u du + \rho\int_t^T \sigma_u dW_u  \right\}
$$
where $\sigma_t$ is the stochastic instantaneous volatility and adapted $W$, $dW dZ = 0$, $\rho$ the correlation between the vol and the stock price, and
$$
Y_T = \exp \left \{ \int_t^T dJ_u \right\}
$$
is the (compensated) jump process (eg a compensated compound Poisson process)? Also, for simplicity I assume that $J$ is independent of the standard Brownian motions $W$ and $Z$ and the instantaneous volatility $\sigma$

If so (if what I wrote above is correct), then I can write the price of a vanilla option as follows, correct?
$$
C^{SVJ}(S_t,K,T) = E_t \left[ C^{BS}\left(S_tX_TY_T,K,T; \bar\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \right) \right]
$$
Here $C^{SVJ}$ is the SVJ model option price, and $C^{BS}$ the Black-Scholes formula, which in the expectation has implied volatility $\bar\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ and
$$
\bar\sigma = \left( \frac{1}{T-t} \int_t^T \sigma^2_u du \right)^{1/2}
$$